# Rcord variable not assigned

Tags: postgresql

HiAll,

when I am running the below function getting the error as

ERROR:  record "v_preorderrec" is not assigned yet.

Even I initialized  v_preorderrec:=null;

Please help me.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION order_f1(p_order_num text)
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
c_order CURSOR FOR
  SELECT od.itemno,
         it.item_cost,
         it.item_code
         FROM orderdtls od
LEFT OUTER JOIN itemdtls it ON (od.itemno = it.itemno)
WHERE od.order_num = p_order_num 
      v_orderrec                 RECORD;
      v_preorderrec             RECORD;
BEGIN
    v_preorderrec:=null;
    open c_order;
      loop
        fetch c_order
          into v_orderrec;

        IF NOT FOUND THEN EXIT; END IF;
         if coalesce(v_preorderrec.itemno::text, '') = '' or
           v_preorderrec.itemno !=
           v_orderrec.itemno then

          perform modorder(v_orderrec.itemno);

        end if;
        v_preorderrec := v_orderrec;
      end loop;
      close c_order;
END;
$function$
;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When the loop is entered for the first time, `v_preorderrec` has never been assigned. You only do that at the _end_ of the loop. So you can't really use any field of that record variable.

Comment: Btw: you don't need a loop or PL/pgSQL for that.

Comment: could you please help me how to handle this.
Initially I want to assign null vales to the fields of  v_preorderrec record.
Once this record v_orderrec is assigned then only I want to assign value to this record v_preorderrec.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon after the cursor declaration.

Comment: By mistake I missed it.
But still same error.
Could you please help me.